# SSIS destination component failing due to current version of the data flow

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, kingswaysoft

I have a working SSIS package. It works from vs, meaning it builds and executes as expected producing results in the CRM.

After I get the generated .ispac file and deploy it in MSSQL server, I fail on executing.

I get an error that looks like this:

> Test Package:Error: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ComponentVersionMismatchException: The version of Create Records is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.  [[The version or pipeline version or both for the specified component is higher than the current version.  This package was probably created on a new version of DTS or the component than is installed on the current PC.]]
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostCheckAndPerformUpgrade(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Int32 lPipelineVersion).

The aforementioned 'Create Record' is the 'Dynamics CRM Destination' component.

There are many who have such issue, I searched the web, but what all suggest is that we change the target version of the MSSQL server from VS, but I tried that and it doesn't work.

**Additional information:**

System: Windows 10 pro

VS: 2015

MSSQL: 13.0.6300.2(so it's sql server 2016)

Kingsway version: v21.2(21.2.0.31501)

The 'TargetServerVersion' is set to: 'SQL Server 2016'

**What have I tried ?**

I have tried to deploy straight from VS, but no luck there.

I ran the same(separately built) SSIS on my local machine where I have vs2019 and sql server 2019, it works fine in here.

I tried to build the project in vs2019 on the main machine and I'm still getting the same error.

**So, do you have any idea what's happening, can you give me some advice ?**

Comment: I did also have such issue previously, but all I did to resolve it was to build the SSIS project on the same machine where the server was located at. Right now I'm doing the same, but it doesn't seem to be a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the question about our integration toolkit. To use any of our toolkits for deployment and scheduled execution, the same version should be installed in possibly three places:

1. On your development machine (this is generally covered by our free Developer license)
2. On your SSIS Integration server
3. On the machine which is used to deploy your SSIS packages to your Integration server (if different from your development machine)

Based on the error message, it is either that you didn't install our Dynamics 365 toolkit or otherwise the installed version on the server is lower than what you have installed on your development workstation.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick answer, I have thought about it. I will provide you some information.

1.The dev machine is a vm, work machine which is the gateway to another servers. In here I should have the latest version of kingsway.
2. SSIS integration server - I understand this as the sql server where I'm trying to deply my package. - I don't know if you have separate tool for sql server, but if you are referring the vm in where I have hosted that sql than I have Windows Server 2008 R2 data center in there - and I don't know what should I install here.
3. It's the same as 1.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about the 2nd part ?

Comment: I installed the other(older) version of KingswaySoft on the development machine and it fixed things, but I'm not sure how good of a solution it is.